# Detection password protected MS Office files in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, ms-office

How can I  detect password protected Ms Office Files?  I'm using C/C++ on Linux.

Comment: Which version of MS Office are the files from?

Comment: office 2010 but want to detect all office versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are in Office 2007 format (e.g. .docx), then their internal storage is either:

1) A zip file of xml docs (if it's not password protected)

2) The old style compound file format (if it IS password protected).

Therefore you could probably do something like this:

1) Check the first few bytes of the file

2) If it's a zip file (non password protected), it'll start with 0x50 0x4b 0x03 0x04.

3) If it's not a zip file, then it's probably password protected. It will start with a different binary signature (e.g. Word 2007 docs start with 0xd0 0xcf 0x11 0xe0 in this case)

Basically, if it's a new .docx or .xlsx, and it DOESN'T start with the zip signature of 0x50 0x4b 0x03 0x04, it's probably password protected.

For other versions of MS Office, it's a bit trickier...

Comment: and i used to detect encrypted archive files with clamav. thanks Baldrick.

Answer (score 0):

The file signature of the encrypted file should be different. for an un-encrypted it is 50 4B 03 04
The first 4 bytes of an encrypted are D0 CF 11 E0 (at least for a docx, might be different for excel,ppt,...

Comment: I have tested, using word 2013, saved a document in Office 2007 format, aka, in .doc file, the first 4 bytes are D0 CF 11 E0, and this file is not encrypted.

Comment: might be an old topic: but for the sake of completeness: Word Version 14.07159.5000 (32 bit); saved as docx: encrypted file first 4 bytes: D0 CF 11 E0; non-encrypted file first 4 bytes: 50 4B 03 04; saved as doc: encryped file first 4 bytes: D0 CF 11 E0; non-encrypted file first 4 bytes: D0 CF 11 E0; conclusion @ET Worker: yes, you are right file headers between encrypted and non-encrypted differ only if saved in docx.